# How to declare an widechar data type in MySQL

Tags: mysql, types, widechar

When I reading a C++ manual, it describe **wchar_t** as this,

> wchar_t Wide character - 2 or 4 bytes
>   1 wide character

It let me think about how to store **wchart**_t kind of data(Like Chinese character) in MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

`wchar_t` is not aware of character encoding. A `wchar_t` might (theoretically) even be 1 or 8 bytes. MySQL is aware of character encoding. So there is no answer that fits all purposes. Make sure that the encoding is the same in MySQL and in the C++ code.